# Update Apollo Schema after Contentful Content Model Changes

Tags: ios, swift, graphql, contentful, apollo-studio

So I watched this tutorial on how to use Contentful & ApolloGraphQL to be able to display data on iOS. After finishing the tutorial I wanted to play around with it some more. In the tutorial it added all the fields that it needed in the beginning but lets say you want to add another field later on.

Example lets say I create a Person as a Content Model in Contentful. Now in the Person Content Model it only has a Single Field "First Name".

Now I go register/upload it into Apollo Studio.

Ooops... I forgot to add another field to my Person Content Model in Contentful. So I go add a field called "Last Name".

Now here is were I am having trouble updating my schema.

In Apollo Studio it is not showing the last name field, I'm pretty sure it has to do with the schema.

So how would I be able to update the schema when I make a change in my Content Model in Contentful?